# How to save an element with WebFlux and ReactiveMongoRepository?

Tags: spring, webflux

I want to write the first program `webFlux` and `ReactiveMongoRepository`.
i have repository:

```
@Repository
public interface personRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person,String> {
        Mono<Person> save(Person person);
}
```

my service:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class personServiceImpl implements personService{

    personRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Flux<Person> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Person> saveOrUpdate(Person person) {
        CompletableFuture<Person> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

            repository.save(person);
            return person;
        });
        return Mono.fromFuture(future);
    }

}
```

and the rest service itself:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class personController {
    personServiceImpl personService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    Flux<Person> getAllPerson(){
        return personService.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Mono<Person> post(@RequestBody Person user) {
        System.out.println("inside***************");
        return personService.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }
}
```

Now when I want to test the service and save or find everyone via postman, then I get an error:

```
"path": "/all",
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
```

That is, as I understand it, the request does not even reach the function, but an error is immediately thrown, where can there be an error here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you calling the endpoints via postman? Do you have any context path in your application?

Comment: @JoãoDias just http://localhost:8080/all

Comment: Can you add the logs of your application when you do the call? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias Unfortunately, there is nothing to add, when I make a request nothing appears in the logs., Thank you for your help

Comment: Then what is the HTTP method that you are using in Postman? Can you add a screenshot of your Postman call? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias I seem to have set the correct parameters and the ```/save``` and ```/all``` methods do not give an error, but after the ```/save``` ```/all```   now always gives an empty list.

Comment: @JoãoDias added picture to post

Comment: But then it is working. The issue seems to be in the save process. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be in `saveOrUpdate()` method. You don't actually need the `CompletableFuture` (why would you in this case?) and the following should work:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class personServiceImpl implements personService{

    personRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Flux<Person> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Person> saveOrUpdate(Person person) {
        return repository.save(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer kind man:) hah,I wanted to work with future in this example, but apparently it doesn't work for some reason.Although I took an example from the site and it somehow works there, but apparently ш still need to look.Thank you again very much!